# Not able to map array of objects in javaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

How do i map the array of object below where i want to display both Module1 and its sub modules?

```
const data = [
    {
        module1 : ["submod1", "submod2"]
    },
    {
        module2 : ["submod3", "submod4"] 
    }
]
```

I also want to pass "module1" and its array as a prop to other component.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCeb.png)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: what the output looks like?

Comment: I've added expected output as image at the end of description. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract module1:

```
const module1Array = data[0].module1.map(sm=> {
        return sm
    }
     );
```

To get all submodule arrays in a new array:

```
const modulesArray = data.map(m => {
    return Object.values(m)[0];
})
```

Why not just pass in data as a prop and map over it in your component? ->

```
const Example = (data) => {

    const modules = data.map(m => {
            return (
            <div>
            <h1>{Object.keys(m)}</h1>
            <p>{Object.values(m)}</p>
            </div>)
        })

     return (
            <div>
                {modules}
            </div>
        )
    }

export default Example
```

Comment: i also want to return module1 and module2. your code is very specific to module 1's subModules

Comment: You should be more specifc with your expected output. The picture your provide already looks like the structure of 'data'. I edited my post to inculde a way to get all sub moudle arrays in a new array.

Comment: thanks for your help. but what if i also want to return "module1" along with its subModules. i want to pass main module("Module1") and its sub modules(submod1,submod2) both as separate props to a component. How can i do that?